# C# winform - Datagridview hide/unhide rendering problem

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a strange thing happening when I unhide some columns and then re-hide them...
(read below)

Image 1 : original situation, columns are hidden, all is OK
[image]
Image 2 : when columns are unhidden, all is OK - **perhaps strange that the images sudenly have a gray background.**
[image]
Image 3 : back to the original situation with some columns hidden => **old text still shows on the datagrid on the place where the images are!**
[image]

At the end of hiding/unhiding columns I added the refresh-method. Without the method, the text appears also.

```
            ....
        Herstellingen_dgOverzicht.Columns["OverzichtHerstellingen_Login_Ingave_Afgehandeld"].Visible = OverzichtHerstellingen_ToonAlleKolommen.Checked;
        Herstellingen_dgOverzicht.Columns["OverzichtHerstellingen_Datum_Afgehandeld"].Visible = OverzichtHerstellingen_ToonAlleKolommen.Checked;

        Herstellingen_dgOverzicht.Refresh();
```

All columns are bound to a datasource (datatable), except for the image-columns because the image shown is computed at runtime and depends on the value of other columns.

Thanks for any input !

Update: code for adding the images:

```
    private void Herstellingen_dgOverzicht_Inzetten_Icoontjes()
    {
        //Herstellingen_dgOverzicht.SuspendLayout();
        Herstellingen_dgOverzicht.CellValueChanged -= Herstellingen_dgOverzicht_CellValueChanged;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow r in Herstellingen_dgOverzicht.Rows)
        {
            r.Cells["OverzichtHerstellingen_Goedkeuring_Icoon"].Value = new Bitmap(1, 1);
            r.Cells["OverzichtHerstellingen_LaptopHersteld_Icoon"].Value = new Bitmap(1, 1);
            r.Cells["OverzichtHerstellingen_Afgewerkt_Icoon"].Value = new Bitmap(1, 1);
            r.Cells["OverzichtHerstellingen_Goedkeuring_Icoon"].ToolTipText = "";
            r.Cells["OverzichtHerstellingen_LaptopHersteld_Icoon"].ToolTipText = "";
            r.Cells["OverzichtHerstellingen_Afgewerkt_Icoon"].ToolTipText = "";
            Application.DoEvents();
            // Goedkeuring
            if (r.Cells["OverzichtHerstellingen_GoekKeuring_Status"].Value.ToString() == "B") // wachten na doorgeven van bestek
            {
                r.Cells["OverzichtHerstellingen_Goedkeuring_Icoon"].Value = Resources.Euro; 
                r.Cells["OverzichtHerstellingen_Goedkeuring_Icoon"].ToolTipText = "Wachten op bestek van de leverancier";
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
            else if (r.Cells["OverzichtHerstellingen_GoekKeuring_Status"].Value.ToString() == "W") // wachten op goedkeuring van de ouders
            {
                r.Cells["OverzichtHerstellingen_Goedkeuring_Icoon"].Value = Resources.unknown; 
                r.Cells["OverzichtHerstellingen_Goedkeuring_Icoon"].ToolTipText = "Wachten op antwoord van de ouders"; 
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
            else if (r.Cells["OverzichtHerstellingen_GoekKeuring_Status"].Value.ToString() == "G") // goedgekeurd
            {
                r.Cells["OverzichtHerstellingen_Goedkeuring_Icoon"].Value = Resources.ok; 
                r.Cells["OverzichtHerstellingen_Goedkeuring_Icoon"].ToolTipText = "ok";
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
            else if (r.Cells["OverzichtHerstellingen_GoekKeuring_Status"].Value.ToString() == "A") // afgekeurd
            {
                r.Cells["OverzichtHerstellingen_Goedkeuring_Icoon"].Value = Resources.nok; 
                r.Cells["OverzichtHerstellingen_Goedkeuring_Icoon"].ToolTipText = "niet ok";
                if (r.Cells["OverzichtHerstellingen_EigendomLL"].Value.ToString() == "True")
                {
                    r.Cells["OverzichtHerstellingen_LaptopHersteld_Icoon"].Value = Resources.nok; 
                    r.Cells["OverzichtHerstellingen_LaptopHersteld_Icoon"].ToolTipText = "niet ok";
                }
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
            else // fout -> niks inzetten
            {  }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Cells["OverzichtHerstellingen_GoekKeuring_Status"].Value.ToString()) &&
                r.Cells["OverzichtHerstellingen_GoekKeuring_Status"].Value.ToString() != "B" && // verder invullen als er leeg laten als er niet gewacht wordt op antwoord van de ouders op een bestek
                r.Cells["OverzichtHerstellingen_GoekKeuring_Status"].Value.ToString() != "W") // vreemd gedrag SQL-server => kleine b komt voor op één of andere manier)
            {
                // Hersteld
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Cells["OverzichtHerstellingen_Laptop_Hersteld"].Value.ToString()))
                {
                    r.Cells["OverzichtHerstellingen_LaptopHersteld_Icoon"].Value = Resources.unknown; r.Cells["OverzichtHerstellingen_LaptopHersteld_Icoon"].ToolTipText = "onbekend";
                }
                else if (r.Cells["OverzichtHerstellingen_Laptop_Hersteld"].Value.ToString() == "True")
                {
                    r.Cells["OverzichtHerstellingen_LaptopHersteld_Icoon"].Value = Resources.ok; r.Cells["OverzichtHerstellingen_LaptopHersteld_Icoon"].ToolTipText = "ok";
                }
                else if (r.Cells["OverzichtHerstellingen_Laptop_Hersteld"].Value.ToString() == "False")
                {
                    r.Cells["OverzichtHerstellingen_LaptopHersteld_Icoon"].Value = Resources.nok; r.Cells["OverzichtHerstellingen_LaptopHersteld_Icoon"].ToolTipText = "niet ok";
                }
                else
                {
                    r.Cells["OverzichtHerstellingen_LaptopHersteld_Icoon"].Value = Resources.unknown; r.Cells["OverzichtHerstellingen_LaptopHersteld_Icoon"].ToolTipText = "onbekend";
                }
                Application.DoEvents();
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Cells["OverzichtHerstellingen_GoekKeuring_Status"].Value.ToString()) &&
                !string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Cells["OverzichtHerstellingen_Laptop_Hersteld"].Value.ToString()))
            {
                // Afgehandeld
                if (r.Cells["OverzichtHerstellingen_Laptop_Afgehandeld"].Value != null && r.Cells["OverzichtHerstellingen_Laptop_Afgehandeld"].Value.ToString() == "True")
                {
                    r.Cells["OverzichtHerstellingen_Afgewerkt_Icoon"].Value = Resources.ok; r.Cells["OverzichtHerstellingen_Afgewerkt_Icoon"].ToolTipText = "ok";
                }
                else if (r.Cells["OverzichtHerstellingen_Laptop_Afgehandeld"].Value != null && r.Cells["OverzichtHerstellingen_Laptop_Afgehandeld"].Value.ToString() == "False")
                {
                    r.Cells["OverzichtHerstellingen_Afgewerkt_Icoon"].Value = Resources.nok; r.Cells["OverzichtHerstellingen_Afgewerkt_Icoon"].ToolTipText = "niet ok";
                }
                else // (r.Cells["OverzichtHerstellingen_Laptop_Afgehandeld"].Value.ToString() == "False")
                {
                    r.Cells["OverzichtHerstellingen_Afgewerkt_Icoon"].Value = Resources.unknown; r.Cells["OverzichtHerstellingen_Afgewerkt_Icoon"].ToolTipText = "onbekend";
                }
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
            //Application.DoEvents();
        }
        Herstellingen_dgOverzicht.CellValueChanged += Herstellingen_dgOverzicht_CellValueChanged;
        //Herstellingen_dgOverzicht.ResumeLayout();
    }
```

Comment: The code that generates and sets (draws?) the images is missing -- Possibly, post code where the objects / variables are written in English, it's much easier to understand what those are for. Or add comments (in English) that explains it. -- A piece of code that just sets the visibility of objects when the value of a CheckBox changes is not exactly useful to understand what's happening *under the hood*. -- Things like these happen when you freeze a Control while it's rendering (e.g., looping its Rows).

Comment: Why are you refreshing `Herstellingen_dgOverzicht.Refresh();`? You should invalidate your data grid view with `Invalidate()` method.

Comment: Invalidate does not solve the problem either...

Comment: @Jimi : The code that adds the images is only run once, when the datagrid is loaded or when a search-option has changed.
This code is not run when columns are hidden/unhidden. I guess c# should take care of putting it all into it's place... not ?

Comment: C# doesn't do anything. You mean, the Control is capable of rendering its content whatever you do. No, it's not. You clearly have rendering issues, usually - as mentioned - caused by code that freezes the Control when some actions are performed. Quite often, with this Control specifically, because there's code that loops the Rows when it's critical that this doesn't happen -- You have to remove all `Application.Doevents()` calls from anywhere in your code. If you think that's needed, it's because the code is not working correctly (is blocking). You have to fix that.

Comment: Note that assigning a Property with an Image coming directly from `Project.Resources` (it's a Factory), creates a new Image each time (and you don't dispose of the previous). You'll run out of handles or GDI resources sooner or later. -- Debug your code, see what is run when you hide / show those Columns.

Comment: The only code that is run on hide/unhide, is the code above.
I'll take the handle-thing in consideration for whenever the problem occurs.
I did the doevents to be able to debug indeed previous render-problems. I found it already strange that inserting a new image did not cleaned-up the old one (hence the new-bitmap(1,1) at the beginning.
When I use virtualmode=true the icons are not showing (but then there are no rendering problems)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved !

=> datagrid.Refresh(); is OK since it is a contraction of Invalidate and Update
([Refresh doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.refresh?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#system-windows-forms-control-refresh)) : .... Forces the control to invalidate its client area and immediately redraw itself and any child controls.

**Solution : I modified the resource-icons from PNG to BMP !**