# C# winform - Datagridview rendering problem on scroll

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, icons

I have a (second) problem with a winform datagridview, specifically with images.

(read below)

Image 1 : first rendering, all OK
[image]
Image 2 : I've scrolled all the way down (other icons where shown) then all the way up... **==> old icons are mixed-up with those that are shown.**
[image]

I did found out that the images on the first **shown** row are having to do something with the 'random' overlapping.

I tried to refresh the datagrid on the scroll-event, but that did not helped.

```
    private void Herstellingen_dgOverzicht_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        Herstellingen_dgOverzicht.Refresh();
    }
```

All columns are bound to a datasource (datatable), except for the image-columns because the image is computed at runtime and depends on the value of other columns.

I guess the question is also related to this thread : [Hiding/Unhiding columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72459036/c-sharp-winform-datagridview-hide-unhide-rendering-problem)

Thanks for any input !

Comment: Have you tried changing the `Herstellingen_dgOverzicht.Refresh();` to `Herstellingen_dgOverzicht.Invalidate();` take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invalidate?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

You would also need to call `Herstellingen_dgOverzicht.Update()` also if you take a look at the `Remarks` section of the link I sent previously

Comment: Hi Connor, thanks for the quick reply. I changed the Refresh to
            Herstellingen_dgOverzicht.Invalidate(); 
            Herstellingen_dgOverzicht.Update(); but that did not the trick...

Comment: Hi Mario, after looking at your previous question, I noticed in your Paint event you aren't removing the bitmap images at all from what I can see, to me it appears that when you're scrolling, what is happening is that when the paint event is being fired, it is loading the new bitmaps and then keeping them visible as there is no code to remove them when the cell isn't in sight, a potentially quick way to check if this is the root cause would be to remove all the bitmaps when you are scrolling and prevent the paint event from creating them until scrolling is complete?

Comment: Saying that, can you confirm that the columns that the bitmaps are located in are actually `DataGridViewImageColumn`'s? As I've just created an app that just populates the grid with images in the columns and it seems to be working for me

Comment: Ouch ! That would be a bummer. I realy tought the datagridview would be able to handle this without messing thins up....

Comment: Yes, they are DataGridViewImageColumn's.

Comment: The solution is the same as in my other thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72459036/c-sharp-winform-datagridview-hide-unhide-rendering-problem

@Makyen : I understand your point of view, however the problem thread is very different but the solution is identical.